# Can't build any project after upgrade to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio on Linux.

And today I have updated it to `version 2.3` stable but now I am not able to build any of my projects or even create a new project.

**There is no error messages, just the building progress works for infinite time !**

**Edit 1:**

I have also updated the Gradle plugin to **`2.14.1`** which was a recommendation message after staring `Android Studio 2.3`

**Edit 2:**

I have tried to build through CL

I used this command: `./gradlew assembleDebug`

but it also did not work! giving this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of
>   120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file:
>   /home/atefhares/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
>     at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
>     at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

---

What should i do?

Comment: Are you able to build your projects from the terminal?

Comment: @cricket_007 I did not try this, i will try and let you know the result

Comment: @cricket_007 Please see my edit, I hope you can help me

Comment: Have you tried the nuclear option of deleting `/home/atefhares/.gradle`?

Comment: @kichik No, I did not, What will happen after deleting ?

Comment: Your next build will be slower while it rebuilds the cache it has there. But the build after that should be fine. You should also verify there are no configuration files in that folder that you may want to keep. Since you're using Android Studio and it was probably created for you, I assume there is nothing important there.

Comment: @kichik thanks for clarification, but I have deleted it and still can't build projects

Comment: Sounds like network timeout. Just remove your local Gradle files and try to install your dry-run project.

Comment: @AnoopM Sorry, can you add more details on how to do that, I haven't did this before!

Comment: You can use Gradle `2.14.1+`, so just download the latest https://gradle.org/install

Comment: Thanks to All you Guys, `Android Studio 2.3` needs at least `Gradle ver 3.3` I have downloaded and used the latest Gradle version  and it bulid successfully

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably had to upgrade Gradle as part of the IDE upgrade.

> Android Gradle Plugin : **2.3.0+**
> Gradle Version:   **3.3+**
>
> You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file

More details here.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: I had to go read the release notes. I always used the latest Gradle anyways. Apps seem to build faster.

Comment: I was depening on the studio to notify me, now I will do like and always update manualy. This version of Android studio seems to be full of issues :( I am facing another one now but it is not related to that post

Comment: I've not used Studio due to the claims of "bugs". IntelliJ IDEA works for me