# Cant Gradle Sync after clicking update Gradle in Android Studio - Error:Gradle 2.14.1 requires Android Gradle plugin 2.1.3 (or newer)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

This is the exact error I am getting when trying to `Gradle Sync` in `Android Studio`. All I did was click the update button when the newer version of Gradle dialog came up.

`Error:Gradle 2.14.1 requires Android Gradle plugin 2.1.3 (or newer) but project is using version 2.1.0.
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.0 and sync project</a><br><a href="https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle">Open Documentation</a>`

This is on my master branch which I know builds/syncs with other people.

**Project Build file**

```
// This is used to improve build server performance by disable pre-dexing when building.
// To enable this feature, use "./gradlew clean assemble -PdisablePreDex"
// Refer: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips
project.ext.preDexLibs = !project.hasProperty('disablePreDex')
subprojects {
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        }
    }
}

// This is used to control Android properties of all modules from the main project.
// Refer: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = '24'
    gradleBuildToolClassPath = 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0"
    }
}
```

**Application Build file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath rootProject.ext.gradleBuildToolClassPath
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Projects
    releaseCompile project(path: ':LibProjects:Android-Library', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':LibProjects:Android-Library', configuration: 'debug')
    compile project(':LibProjects:photoview')
    compile project(':LibProjects:viewpagerindicator')

    // Maven libraries
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:+'
    compile 'com.tonicartos:stickygridheaders:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.7@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.6.0') { exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' }
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-base:4.11.0@aar')
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:4.11.0@aar')

    // File libraries
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile(name:'adsnative-sdk-2.5.3', ext:'aar')

    // Testing
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fusionprojects.edmodo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        versionCode 50111
        versionName "6.5.2"
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // These statements are required for solving a very annoying gradle build error:
        // "Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        // Refer: http://blog.csdn.net/zhouzme/article/details/18923293
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')

        // Testing
        androidTest.setRoot('androidTest')
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Gradle wrapper**

```
#Tue Sep 06 16:30:01 PDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Have you tried to click on the link that says:
"Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.0 and sync project"?

Comment: @krlos77 Yup, it gives me a different error. `Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection` And gives me the options of `re-downloading dependencies and sync` or `stop gradle build processes`. Both do not fix the issue.

Comment: Try changing this line:
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
for this:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-rc1'

Comment: I had the same problem check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588000/cant-build-any-project-after-upgrade-to-android-studio-2-3)

Comment: all you have to do is download the lasted gradle version!

Comment: @krlos77 We are using `Realm DB library` so it requires to use the realm-gradle-plugin.

Comment: @AtefHares I've tried to upgrade to the latest version of Gradle and the plugin and still no luck

Answer (score 1):

You may try this :

Go to --> **gradle.wrapper.properties**

and replace the distribution Url with this :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip
```

Hope this helps !