# Android Studio stuck at building gradle project info

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 2.3 and whenever I try to create a new project or open some project, it gets stuck at this point "Building "******" Gradle project info" please suggest me some solution.

Comment: wait till the gradle sync is completed as because in my case the gradle was being updated so it kept syncing till the new version of gradle was downloaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't build any project after upgrade to Android Studio 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588000/cant-build-any-project-after-upgrade-to-android-studio-2-3)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is likely downloading Gradle zip file,
 e.g: `/Users/user****/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip`.
you should manual download it or check network.

Comment: ugh its been quite a while and many version since! I always forgot it does this on fresh install. Would be great if they place indicator/text messages that it does!!!

Answer (score 1):

Download manually the stable version of gradle from [gradle-X.X-all.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

and extract into `/Users/[yourUsername]/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-x.x-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/`

Answer (score 0):

you can download your gradle.x.zip and replace  /Users/user****/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip